# Gaussian blur over (or random walk in) a surface mesh

Tags: differential-geometry, markov-chains, martingales, random-walk, discrete-geometry

Let $V$ be the set of mesh vertices, connected by edges $E$, forming a mesh that represents a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. On this mesh a function $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined. For example, $f$ could represent a color or temperature over the surface.

How can I numerically compute a (generalized) "Gaussian blur" of $f$ on the surface?

($E$ could be such that the mesh is topologically similar to a rectangular grid or if convenient edges could be added so that faces are subdivided further into triangular, and therefore planar, faces.)

---

My thoughts, for what they're worth:

The probability distribution of a particle's position after a random walk in the mesh is a Gaussian blur of the initial probability distribution, I think. This probability distribution can be reached by starting with $f$ and repeatedly updating for random 1-hops in the mesh, Markov-chain-style, but I don't know how to assign probabilities to transitions along each outgoing edge from a vertex.

In symmetrical cases such as a planar square grid, it is obvious that each outgoing edge carries equal weight/transition-probability, but how to determine these weights/transition-probabilities in the case of a general/irregular/curved mesh? I feel the expected position after a hop from a given vertex should lie somewhere along the span of the mean curvature normal (which can be calculated [like this](http://http.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/meshpapers/MeyerDesbrunSchroderBarr.pdf)) vector from that vertex, and that this is the generalized version of the Martingale property of planar random walks. This constraint would fully determine the relative weights/transition-probabilities of each edge if the vertex in question has valence 3, but in the far more common case where vertices have valence >3, the weights/transition-probabilities are under-determined without some additional constraint/optimization. Could it be that the weights should be decided in this case by maximizing the post-hop variance?